# Custom admin grid filter - error when searching joined column

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, join

I have a custom grid with columns created by joining a flat table to the customer collection. 
Everything works fine except when i try to filter the list using any of the column added from the flat table.

In `_prepareCollection()`

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

    $collection->joinTable(array('up' => 'mymodule/userprofile'), 'mageuserid=entity_id', array('*'), null, 'left');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $record));
    $collection->addFilterToMap("shoptitle", "up.shoptitle");
    $collection->addFilterToMap("contactnumber", "up.contactnumber");
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
```

Added columns in `_prepareColumns()`

```
    $this->addColumn('shoptitle', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Shop Title'),
        'index' => 'shoptitle',
        'type' => 'text',
    ));
    $this->addColumn('contactnumber', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Telephone'),
        'width' => '100',
        'index' => 'contactnumber',
    ));
```

Here is my error log

```
    exception 'Exception' with message 'Non Object found for attribute shoptitle' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php:785
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php(1377): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->isAttributeStatic('shoptitle')
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php(321): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_getAttributeConditionSql('shoptitle', Array, 'inner')
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php(341): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addAttributeToFilter('shoptitle', Array)
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(472): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addFieldToFilter('shoptitle', Array)
    #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(457): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_addColumnFilterToCollection(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column))
    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(517): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_setFilterValues(Array)
    #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\local\Test\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Partners\Grid.php(52): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
    #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(626): Test_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Partners_Grid->_prepareCollection()
    #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
    #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
    #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\local\Test\Mymodule\controllers\Adminhtml\Mymodule\PartnersController.php(56): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Test_Mymodule_Adminhtml_Mymodule_PartnersController->gridAction()
    #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('grid')
    #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\mage_test\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #17 {main}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer rafal-kos helped a lot for me to solve a big client issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use something like that :

```
$collection->joinTable(array('mup' => 'marketplace/userprofile'), 'mageuserid=entity_id', array('*'), null, 'left');
```

and then add filter callback on specific columns :

```
$this->addColumn('shoptitle', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Shop Title'),
            'index'     => 'shoptitle',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterShopTitle'),
            'order_callback'            => array($this, '_sortShopTitle')
        ));
```

`_filterShopTitle` function body

```
    /**
     * Function that handle filter on custom table
     *
     * @param $collection
     * @param $column
     */
    protected function _filterShopTitle($collection, $column)
    {
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue() === null) {
            return;
        }

        $collection->getSelect()->where('mup.shoptitle like ?', '%' . $column->getFilter()->getValue() . '%');
    }
```

and for sorting :

```
    /**
     * Function that handle sorting on custom table
     *
     * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection $collection
     * @param Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column          $column
     */
    function _sortShopTitle($collection, $column)
    {
        $collection->getSelect()->order($column->getIndex() . ' ' . strtoupper($column->getDir()));
    }
```